# CodedUI Test + deferred/promise: Mouse.Click() does the click, httpPost is called, no 'then' or 'finally' being hit

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, coded-ui-tests

I am automating a test where a user clicks a 'calculate' button.

A number of values are calculated, which afterwards are displayed in a new grid. On a manual click, this calculation takes about 4 seconds for the extra control to show up on screen.

When I run the test the button is clicked correctly, but after that the application freezes.

I have tried:

- WaitForControlReady
- WaitForControlEnabled
- WaitForControlVisible
- WaitForControlExist
- TryGetClickablePoint
- Thread.Sleep
- Playback.Wait
- Playback.PlaybackSettings.DelayBetweenActions
- Do { Thread.Sleep } while (!TryGetClickablePoint())
- Retry

All with no success.

The calculate button will call a javascript method(with a deferred/promise) which in turn will call a c# method to do the actual calculation.

When there is no Playback.Wait(5000) after the click, the http.post towards the c# code is not being made.

So I put a small wait of 5 seconds and now the call is being made, and I can see a response coming in. However, the '.then' (or the '.finally') is not being hit.

I have looked here [CodedUI Test- Mouse.Click() on control dose not give expected outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693352/codedui-test-mouse-click-on-control-dose-not-give-expected-outcome)
and here [Coded UI Tests - Clicking button does suddenly not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347637/coded-ui-tests-clicking-button-does-suddenly-not-work) but I wasn't able to deduct a solution from either of those.

Any help whatsoever will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodedUI is injecting a javascript as soon as the browser opens, unfortunately this breaks the way Ajax calls are handled and breaks the site.

You need to add the following to your app.config

```
<add key="WebWaitForReadyLevel" value="3"/>
```

https://fluentbytes.com/how-to-prevent-codedui-tests-from-breaking-angular-ajax-calls/